# Finding the size of n-ary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

In C, I tried to find the size of n-ary tree like this. I know why this is wrong.
but couldn't find out any way to return the size of n-ary tree.

Can someone suggest a way to return the size of tree.

```
int size(struct Node*root)
{
    int sz=0;
    if(root==NULL)
      return 0;
    else
    {
      for(int i=0;i<N;i++) sz=sz+1+size(root->child[i]);
    } 
 return sz;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
int size(struct Node*root)
{
    int sz=1;
    if(!root) return 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) sz+=size(root->child[i]);
    return sz;
}
```

Comment: it was wrong because sz variable is adding up it's previous value for each of the child, instead we must just add 1 after counting each node